# Figcaption Not Aligning Correctly Under Image

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to layout 3 pictures one straight after another on the same line, each having their own 'Figcaption'. But the figcaption as seen in the image below is completely not centered and the figure area is not aligned correctly with the image either. I need the figure to take up exactly the same space as the image otherwise it's pushing the other images to the next line which I don't want happening. So basically, what would be the best way about setting the specific 131px size for the figure and then making the figcaption exactly aligned with the image when I set the text to align in the center?

Image of Problem - [http://i.imgur.com/s3aoUqb.png](https://i.imgur.com/s3aoUqb.png)
(The Figure is not aligned at all with the image)

HTML and CSS:

```css
    html, body { /* ### */
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
    }
    body {
        background-color: #fdfdfd;
        font-family: Arial, "Open Sans", sans-serif-light, sans-serif, "Segoe UI";
    }
    #wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin:0 0 0 20%; /* ### */
    }
    #sidebar {
        background-color: #212528;
        position: fixed;
        width: 20%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #nav {
        color: #DADADA;
        display: block;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    #nav ul {
        padding-left: 0;
    }
    #nav li {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0.75em 0 0.75em 0;
        text-align: center;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    #nav li:hover {
        background:#333;
    }
    #nav li a {
        display: block;
        padding: 0.5em 0;
    }
    .link {
        text-align: right;
        margin-right: 25%;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
    }
    #welcometext {
        text-align: center;
        font-style: italic;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 1em;
        margin-top: 2em;
    }
    #searchbar {
        width: 70%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        padding: 1em 1em 0.5em 1em;
        text-align: right;
    }
    #searchbar input {
        max-width: 95%;
    }
    #sectionone {
        /*position: fixed;*/
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 80%;
    }
    #containerone {
        margin-top: 0;
        width: 80%;
        height: 100%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        text-align: center;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #DADADA;
        box-shadow: inset 0 -6px 0 0 #fdfdfd, inset 0 -8px 0 0 #DADADA;
    }
    #header {
        margin: 6em 0 6em 0;
    }
    #logo h1 {
        color: #ed786a;
        text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        letter-spacing: 13px;
    }
    #logo p {
        margin-top: -0.6em;
        color: #888888;
        letter-spacing: 4px;
        font-size: 0.85em;
    }
    #sectiontwo {
        width: 80%;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    #containertwo {
        width: 80%;
        height: 100%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #sectwohead{
        margin: 2em 0 2em 0;
        color: #888888;
    }
    #bestsellerimages{
        float: left;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        margin: 0 0 2em 0;
    }
    #bestsellerimages img{
        padding: 0 1em 0 1em;
    }
    #bestsellerimages figure{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 131px;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Lakeside Books</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="masterstyle.css">
        <meta name="viewsize" content="width-device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    
        <!--[if IE]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="_http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="sidebar">
            <nav id="nav">
                <h3 id="welcometext">Welcome To<br>Lakeside Books</h3>
                <div id="searchbar">
                    <form action="http://www.example.com/search.php">
                        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="...Search Book Title"/>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a class="link">
                            Home
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="link">
                            Categories
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="link">
                            Bestsellers
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="link">
                            Contact
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    
        <div id="sectionone">
            <div id="containerone">
                <div id="header">
                    <div id="logo">
                        <h1>LAKESIDE BOOKS</h1>
                        <p>KERRYS LOCAL BOOKSTORE</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div id="sectiontwo">
            <div id="containertwo">
                <h2 id="sectwohead">Best Selling Books Right Now</h2>
                    <div id="bestsellerimages">
                        <figure>
                            <img src="Images/4.jpg" alt="book1" height="200" width="131">
                            <figcaption>The Girl On The Train - Paula Hawkins</figcaption>
                        </figure>
                        <figure>
                            <img src="Images/3.jpg" alt="book2" height="200" width="131">
                        </figure>
                        <figure>
                            <img src="Images/5.jpg" alt="book1" height="200" width="131">
                        </figure>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the `padding-left` set on the `img`. Try changing:

```
#bestsellerimages img{
    padding: 0 1em 0 1em;
}
```

to:

```
#bestsellerimages img{
    padding: 0;
}
```

in your CSS.

Comment: Right. The figure itself is only 131 pixels wide, but the image is 131 pixels plus its padding, so it overflows out of the figure.

Comment: Indeed. The box model strikes again.